# jQuery form validation with tips

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

I'm looking for a form validation plugin which displays a tip on the side to show if the input was valid or not.

Something like the following, that Yahoo! uses for their signup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Browse thru the 25 jquery Form plugins and see which one works for you. 
http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elementsr